# My IntelliJ do not hint the out's method in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I written a `hello.jsp`:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.text.* , java.lang.String" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My JSP `hello.jsp` starting page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        // 写java代码
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        String curDate = sdf.format(new Date());
        //print the information
        out.print("hello"+curDate);  // Here, my IntelliJ did not hint the print method, and also show Cannot resolve method 'print'
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

The error show:

> Cannot resolve method 'print(java.lang.String)'

The snapshot, you can see the print method is red color:

[image]

But I run this jsp in my browser, it prints the information in my browser.

[image]

Comment: Mmmm scriptlets. Run away, run away...

Comment: @Boris the Spider, I do not understand, sir.

Comment: I mean that using scriptlets became bad practice in 2001 with the release of JSP tag libraries. It became extremely bad practice shortly after when the Java community realised just how awful they were to maintain and test. It's now 2017, almost two decades later, I am surprised that Intellij doesn't just shut down and refuse to start up until you remove this abomination from your code. Consider yourself lucky it only refuses to autocomplete.

Comment: thanks for your patience explain.

Comment: You need to have the servlet jars on your build path.

Answer (score 3):

I was having same issue on IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3.2. Then I put the dependency mentioned by leela Daka on my pom.xml, reloaded the pom and It worked! The only change I've made was on version to **2.2** to match with Tomcat 7 that uses JSP 2.2.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope></dependency>
    <dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include '*lib*' directory of Tomcat into your project.
If using IntelliJ IDE: file->project structure->libraries-> + ->[lib folder of your tomcat]

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
<artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope></dependency>
```

And run clean, install cmds from mvn life cycle.
An option will appear in intellij ide on top right asking to re load the project click on that and it removes this error in Intellij ide.